# Run Continuum in the cloud and trigger CI jobs in our on-premise CI server without changing the firewall

Tags: continuum

We want to host Continuum in AWS, but run build jobs in our on-premise Jenkins server without opening a port in the firewall for Continuum to talk to Jenkins. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by installing a stand-alone Continuum worker.  Below I have linked an article on the Continuum community site which will describe the necessary steps to do that.

https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne_Continuum/Continuum_Installation_and_Maintenance/Continuum_Installation/Installation_and_Configuration_of_a_Stand-alone_Continuum_Worker

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Consider adding a summary or steps from the article in your answer, as links can die over time.